# Load list into numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

How would I go about loading a list into a numpy matrix, with different rows/columns.

I.e.

```
i=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

would be loaded in for example as

```
np.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Comment: `numpy.array(i).reshape(3,3)`?

Comment: `np.array(i).reshape(3, 3)`?

Comment: I think we have a consensus...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Wait, OP mentioned matrix, not array? Premature dupe...?

Comment: Ah it's the same thing: `np.matrix(i).reshape(-1, 3)`

Comment: Awesome, can this be done for abitrarily large lists?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I prefer to pretend `np.matrix` doesn't exist.